# What does Ozupftn mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, bavarian

The quotation below is copied verbatim from the closed-captioning of the latest episode<sup>1</sup> of *Tatort*:

> Da spielt die Brass-Band und die Ozupftn spielen auch.

It is possible that *Ozupftn* is a typo, or an abbreviation of sorts.

Can someone tell me what this word means?  If it is an abbreviation, what is the full form?  If it is a typo, what is the correct (and hopefully Google-able) form?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [**Freies Land**](https://www.ardmediathek.de/tv/Tatort/Tatort-Freies-Land-H%C3%B6rfassung/Das-Erste/Video?bcastId=602916&documentId=52887336), at around 28:44.</sup>

Comment: It is Bavarian dialect and literally means *Angezupften*, which is likely one or more string instruments as e.g. *zither*.

Comment: @guidot Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pun on "`O'zapft` [is']", i.e. the [act of opening a beer barrel](https://www.oktoberfest.net/o-zapft-is-en/). As Guidot pointed out, in a Bavarian dialect it sounds rather similar to "zupfen", which means plucking the strings of an instrument.

To provide some context, this is from a "Tatort" episode that plays out in (and it produced in) Bavaria, context is that some young men want to go to the city to party (or as their father alleges, to go on a binge, which has them protest that they just want to listen to the two bands mentioned), and "O'zapft is'" is a phrase typically used when the first keg of beer is tapped to open large festival (think Oktoberfest).

Comment: I'm not convinced of a pun and this hypothesis (as well as your first sentence) does contribute little to the explanation.

Comment: @guidot, go ahead. Dies ist ein freies Land.

Comment: @guidot The pun was the 1st thing coming to mind (I am a native Bavarian).

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see a closer connection between Ozupfn and Ozapfn as between Anzupfen and Anzapfen. So in my opinion this is not the point of the pun.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any connection with "O'zapft is!" either. "Ozapft" and "ozupft" are just the Bavarian versions of "angezapft" and "angezupft" with no further connection. The saying "O'zupft is!" is  actuallz occasionally used when celebrating the start of the hops harvest in the meaning "it has been plucked!".

Answer (score 5):

In the audio track, there is one word more:

> Da spielt die *Minger* Brass-Band und die Ozupftn spielen auch.

"Minger" (could probably also be transcribed as "Minga") is bavarian for "Münchner", and while "die Ozupftn" certainly corresponds to "die Angezupften" in standard german, the context makes it pretty clear that both are proper names (of two bands playing *da*).

Anzupfen (to pluck at sth.) hints at string instruments.

However, grammatically, *die Ozupftn* / *die angezupften* is a *Partizip Perfekt Passiv*, thus the bearers of that name are literally the ones having been plucked at, not the ones doing the plucking.

According to `Johann Christoph Adelung: Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart`, [anzupfen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=DA02838#XDA02838) is used in the upper german dialects to express the meaning of [anz**a**pfen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=DA02817#XDA02817), which in turn means to pester/bother/taunt someone. So, literally, the band calls itself the pestered ones.